# How can you tell the rough phase of star formation a star is in from the current radius and mass of the star?

Tags: star-formation

This question is really bothering me since I'm getting mixed thoughts. The masses of the stars in question are 0.92 solar masses and 0.29 solar masses. The diameters are 1,400,000 km and 750,000 km respectively. Personally, I think they're regular main sequence stars and are not in a intermediate stage of star formation, but I'm unsure about this. Is there a method that can be used to figure out the rough phase of star formation that this star is in?

Comment: You think a main sequence star (or any kind of star) has a radius of $10^4$ au ??

Comment: No such star satisfies the property of having a radius of 4500 AU and 10000 AU. Do you mean solar radii instead?

Comment: @RobJeffries Sorry about that, I don't know what I was thinking about the diameters of the stars. I updated the values for the question.